# Business logic of the CheckBox listener inside a ListView

Tags: android

I have implemented a custom adapter for my ListView, that includes a CheckBox in each row.

As I have my click listener in my custom adapter, I'm forced to implement there my business logic (that is, what happens when a CheckBox is clicked... access the database, etc).

Is that correct? Wouldn't be a better practice to implement that business logic outside the custom adapter? (I think the adapter should only care about visualization).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..hope it helps you

```
lv_Archiveist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(view.findViewById(R.id.chkbox).isChecked())
                {
                //your method//
                    //you can also get the position of your selected checkbox by the parameter  "position"
                }
```

Comment: But "your method" is a method inside the custom adapter, isn't it? It should be outside the custom adapter.

Comment: It is in the activity class and lv_Archiveist is a ListView

Comment: In my question I was referring to a custom list adapter (that extends an ArrayAdapter), and the business logic that I have implemented is inside the getView method. So my question is, could I place it outside the custom adapter? How? and how could I call it?

Comment: yes,in my code, I have a custom adapter which extends BaseAdapter.I've declared checkbox in it.I also have a textview.We can access these controls in the Activity class in which we use the ListView. The adapter can be accessed from the listView by the Method posted above..So, you can place the business logic outside the Adapter class also.you could refer that which checkbox is checked by using onCheckchangeListener and access it's relevant textbox or whatever control's data using the "position" parameter.plz post if any query,I'll try to post my program if possible..hope it helps :-)

Comment: Oh, posting some code would be very interesting :) Does it work every time a checkbox is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

I'd only mark the item on `CheckBox` click, and perform all the logic on different button click that would be outside of a `ListView` (similar to how iPhone handle editing the table). I can't remember the situation where `CheckBox` is used to perform some action itself.

Comment: The problem is how can I call some method outside my list adapter?

Comment: Is this a problem? Define this public method in your adapter's class and you would be able to call it on your adapter's object, for example by getting it from listView `((YourCustomAdapter)listView.getAdapter()).doSomethingWithCheckedItems();`

Comment: Ok, that would be for doing something with all checked items in a bulk. But how would you do it every time a single item is checked?

Comment: As I said, I'd not perform logic on every item check, I'd only mark the item as checked/unchecked. This logic will be in adapter, but the business logic will be outside of it.

Comment: That's my question, how could I place it outside the custom adapter? And for the needs of my app, it needs to perform logic on every checkbox click.

Comment: I think you're doing it wrong performing an action on checkbox click. But if you want, you could pass a custom listener to your adapter, perform a method `onClick` or smthn on it in your adapter's class, and implement this listener whenever you want to.

Comment: I don't understand your suggestion. You talk about implementing the custom listener in my adapter, where it is implemented right now, but my question is how can I perform that logic outside the adapter.

Comment: I'm talking about implementing the listener outside of your adapter, but invoking its method inside adapter. Something like you do setting `onClickListener`, you could implement it in outer class and pass this class' object to `setOnClickListener` method.